# Custom error handlig function to not catch errorcontrolled flow (with @)

Tags: php, error-handling

I made my custom error and exception handler functions (in core file) and set them via:

```
set_error_handler('custom_error_handler');
set_exception_handler('custom_exception_handler');
```

Elsewhere in my code I validate GET parameters from the request from $_GET superglobal. Even though some of the GET variables may not be passed/set, I validate and store them. To avoid user errors I put the errorcontrol PHP operator i.e. '@', it successfully hides unnecessary errors from the user.

Also, I am familiar how the '@' operator works, basically it sets error reporting to 0 on the line where an expression has that operator, then turns it back on.

My goal is to still have custom error handling functions (mainly for easier debugging and error output, I'm tired of unnecessary HTML tags that PHP outputs on errors), but retain the option to not log to users errors that these custom error handling function catch even though the operator '@' is used for some expressions.

Below is the example of the problem in more detail:

```
function custom_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    $res = [
        'error_number' => $errno,
        'error_severity' => ERROR_LEVELS[$errno], // custom constant to get textual severity of the error (not important)
        'error_message' => $errstr,
        'error_file' => $errfile,
        'error_line' => $errline
    ];

    // logging to file with UID...

    if(DEBUG) { // if debugging is on (false for production)
        http_response_code(500);
        print_r(json_encode($res));
    }
    else {
        http_response_code(500);
        print_r(json_encode(['error_uid' => $log_uid]));
        exit;
    }
}

set_error_handler('custom_error_handler');

echo $x;
// unset/unknown variable - should print out error and continue with execution since it is a notice (or warning I'm not sure)
$guid = @$_GET['guid']
// should not print error if '$_GET['guid']' is not set/is empty
```

In this setup, both errors get logged!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This sounds like the XY problem. First, I've never come across an instance when a PHP error was not a result of a programming error. The 2 example instances are bugs. Second, even with error_reporting off / @ there is a signficant performance impact from error. i.e. they need to be logged and fixed. Yes, it's not good to dump errors to the browser. "basically it sets error reporting to 0" - no, it suppresses the error - see https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php AND EXPLICITLY CALLS ANY custom error handler.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is EXACTLY the specified behaviour of the system

Comment: Yes, of course @symcbean, custom error handling functions catch ALL errors and it is THE way it works in PHP, I've read the manual... But, if you had understood my question, my goal was to ask if any workaround was possible. Just for you, I'll greatly simplify my question: "Is there a way to get PHP errors and exceptions in a nicer format, other than the default text with HTML tags. Preferably in JSON format with all the data needed for debugging. Keep in mind I'm obsessed with @ and want to use it, forever". Does this clarify enough?

Comment: You just need to turn display_errors off.

Comment: I need all errors to be displayed. nvmnd I posted the answer that works for me

Answer (score -1, accepted):

do this

```
if (error_reporting() != E_ALL) {   
    return false;
}
```

so the whole function would look like

```
function custom_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    $res = [
        'error_number' => $errno,
        'error_severity' => ERROR_LEVELS[$errno],
        'error_message' => $errstr,
        'error_file' => $errfile,
        'error_line' => $errline
    ];

    // logging to file with UID...

    // if suppressed error
    if (error_reporting() != E_ALL) {
        return false;
    }
        
    if(DEBUG) {
        http_response_code(500);
        print_r(json_encode($res));
    }
    else {
        http_response_code(500);
        print_r(json_encode(['error_uid' => $log_uid]));
        exit;
    }
}

set_error_handler('custom_error_handler');

echo $x;
// will print error
$guid = @$_GET['guid']
// wont print error
```

anyone will learn and understand better if they read themselves, so:

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421908/detect-in-custom-error-handler-if-a-php-error-was-actually-suppressed-by) question and the newest answer (for PHP > 8.0.0)

and this [user notice](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php#125938) on the documentation